# Changing a python variable based on its content

Tags: python, django

I'm writing some stuff with Django and it's becoming a bit of a mess. I'm trying to create an app that can run and return data from up-loadable python modules with a text input field for calling functions.
Most of it's working and I can call functions with no arguments.
The problem is with entering functions which require arguments, as any input that's passed to python is in string form, meaning if I enter: `param('a',[foo])` to call the function:

```
def param(a,b): 
   return "Hello world" + a + b
```

The function will return:

```
"Hello world'a'[foo]"
```

Basically I need a way to take a string and convert it to literal python code... if that's possible so that I can treat this input box as if it were the python console.

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly welcome! I do realize this isn't a very pythonic way of doing things.

EDIT due to concerns about security: I am not too worried about security issues as this will only ever be a local project.

Comment: You can use `eval`, but it's dangerous to do that to user input.

Comment: Be sure to know what you are doing there. Running uploaded code opens several hells of security issues! I don't know what you are building, but think hard if that is really necessary, and how to make it secure...

Comment: @Alistair401 a better question is why you think this is the right way to solve this question (hint: its not)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks. A bit cryptic but I'll try think of some other methods. I've got my code running a rudimentary system of making predictions on what you mean based on the content of the string but it's ugly and I'm not proud of it at all. Any other hints available?

Comment: @Alistair401 How do you want for the `param` function to work?

Comment: @IgorHatarist Well I'd like for it to act like it should. That is to return an error as you can't concatenate a list to a string. It should also only treat "a" as the string instead of "'a'" with the extra quotation marks.

Comment: @Alistair401 sorry, I wasn't sure what output would you expect. I have undeleted my answer and updated it with the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), it is more limited than eval but does not pose the risks:

*Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.*

```
from ast import literal_eval

def param(a,b): 
   return "Hello world" + literal_eval(a) + literal_eval(b)

In [9]: param('" foo"', "'bar'")
Out[9]: 'Hello world foobar'
```

You can use a try/except to catch when you want a or b are just meant to  be strings:

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` for that.

```
def param(a, b): 
    return "Hello world" + eval(a) + eval(b)
```

It will surely produce an error if you try to concatenate a string and a list:

```
>>> param('", an unsafe world!"', '"!!!"')
'Hello world, an unsafe world!!!!'

>>> param('", an unsafe world!"', '[]')
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

As of getting rid of the quotation marks, I guess you can either add the quotation marks yourself (like `eval('"{0}"'.format(a))`) or use an `ast.literal_eval()` as proposed by Padraic.